# Jenkins keeps clearing workspace upon starting a new job although not set to

Tags: shell, jenkins, makefile

I am currently developing a NMEA sentence parser and using Jenkins to build and run test cases automically after a push on the Git repository. I have two jobs, BuildTestProgram and RunTestProgram_ImplementedFunctions. The first of these works fine as you would imagine, although it dumps the .o and executable file into /bin within the project directory. I have set it up on Jenkins that once the first job completes the second job runs and cd's into the /bin and launches the test program executable (./nmea-parser-tests).

The problem I am having is once the second job starts to run the first thing it does is 'ls' so I can look at the console output afterwards and see whats going on - even though I have removed all connections from the Git repo for that specific job it still reverts back to the original repo, without the /bin folder and the .o files and executable inside.

BuildTestProgram shell script:

```
qmake NMEA_Parser-Tests.pro
make
```

RunTestProgram_ImplementedFunctions shell script:

```
ls
cd /home/dptc/jenkins/workspace/BenjaminColliganN0942934/RunTestProgram_ImplementedFunctions/bin
./nmea-parser-tests --log_level=all --run_test=IsSupportedFormat
./nmea-parser-tests --log_level=all --run_test=ChecksumMatches
./nmea-parser-tests --log_level=all --run_test=ParseSentence
./nmea-parser-tests --log_level=all --run_test=HasCorrectNumberOfFields
./nmea-parser-tests --log_level=all --run_test=ReadSentences
```

Just to clarify, I have to do this in separate jobs as-per my coursework specification unfortunately.

Any more information needed please just ask.

I have had this problem for a couple days now somehow.

Answer (score 0):

BuildTest job fetches the code and builds it. The code and build output of this job shall be present in this job's workspace.
RunTest job needs the build output of BuildTest job to run the tests.

You can achieve this via either of the following:

- Access BuildTest job's workspace directly in your RunTest job.

  ls
  cd /home/.../.../BuildTest/code/bin/
  ./runTest.sh
- In BuildTest job, use `Archive the artifacts` Post-build Actions to archive the build output.
  In RunTest job, use `Copy artifacts from another project` Build step to copy BuildTest job's artifacts into RunTest job's workspace.